# AWS Cognito authentication against Azure AD fails with "scope doesn't exist"

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

Cognito talks to AAD via OpenID Connect. The full error message is:

```
AADSTS650053: The application 'dev-aws-cognito' asked for scope 'openid email' that doesn't exist on the resource '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'. Contact the app vendor.
```

For context, `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` is the "Microsoft Graph" (https://graph.microsoft.com) standard object. It appears during the Microsoft login flow:
[image: error message]

In `Azure > Active Directory > App Registrations > dev-aws-cognito > API permissions`, I granted the following:
[image: permissions]

That doesn't appear to help. What is missing?

Comment: Could you please try granting admin consent to the API permissions and try.

Comment: Did so, still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in AWS Cognito, the requested scopes in "Identity Provider > Authorized scopes" were separated by newlines, not spaces.